# Automation tools for building C application using Notepad

Tags: c, windows, apache, automation, httpmodule

I'm a **novice** in C programming and I just use **notepad** to code my C application. Now I'm learning how to create **apache http server module** in C. I know how to create C module for apache but the process is **repetitive** and tiresome. For example, when I modify the C source code for the module, I need to repeat the whole process. So, now I'm looking for tools that can automate the process.

Here is the process in building the apache module in C:

1. Start Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)
2. Change directory to apache bin directory: `cd C:\PROGRA~1\APACHE~1\Apache2.2\bin`
3. Run this command: `apxs -llibhttpd -llibapr-1 -llibaprutil-1 -c mod_helloworld.c`
4. NOTE: this command will create `mod_helloworld.so` file
5. Stop apache server using this command: `net stop apache2.2`
6. Copy `mod_helloworld.so` file to `C:\PROGRA~1\APACHE~1\Apache2.2\modules` folder
7. Run this command: `apxs -i -n "helloworld" mod_helloworld.la`
8. Start apache server using this command: `net start apache2.2`
9. Browse the web page in Firefox to observe the latest changes made in apache module

My apache module purpose is to serve **dynamic web pages**. So I frequently need to make changes to the module. Now I repeat my question: `What are the tools for me to automate this repetitive process`?

Comment: If the steps are that simple, you might just start off by writing a .bat file.

Comment: A simple `.cmd` script can handle that (except the browsing part, that's you that does it).

Comment: @James McNellis: Thanks, I need to google about .bat file. I don't know what is that.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description, you could probably stick this in a .bat file, and run that

```
cd C:\PROGRA~1\APACHE~1\Apache2.2\bin
apxs -llibhttpd -llibapr-1 -llibaprutil-1 -c mod_helloworld.c
net stop apache2.2
copy mod_helloworld.so C:\PROGRA~1\APACHE~1\Apache2.2\modules
apxs -i -n "helloworld" mod_helloworld.la
net start apache2.2
```

In general, if you find yourself running a series of commands over and over, it's time to put them all into a script of some sort